# Strange assignment in python

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a mutation (genetic algorithm) operator in python. My population is an array of tuples - (array (solution) , float (objective function)).
Considering in this case the size of the solution is 1, here is my code for testing:

```
position = 4
ind1 = population[position]
p1 = ()
p1 = ind1[0]
point = 0)
new_point = 4
print "bla", population
population[position][0][point] = new_point
print "pop", population
if(flag == 1):
    ind1 = (p1,dist(p1))
    population[position] = ind1
else:
    ind1 = (p1,heuristic_dist(p1))
    population[position] = ind1
```

Here is the initial population:

bla [([11], 0.0015072271967127016), ([8], 0.0573155547768569), ([8], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569), ([2], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569), ([2], 0.0573155547768569), ([2], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569), ([8], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569)]

I would expect to replace only the tuple in the position 4 but instead it replaces ALL tuples containing the value [2], as below:

pop [([11], 0.0015072271967127016), ([8], 0.0573155547768569), ([8], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569), ([8], 0.0573155547768569), ([4], 0.0573155547768569)]

Why? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I ran your code and it gives me `SyntaxError` on the line `point = 0)` If I remove that parenthesis I get `NameError: name 'population' is not defined`. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the way you constructed `bla`. If you assigned *the same tuple* to different elements of the list `bla`, then you have stored multiple references to that single tuple. Changing one of them changes the target of the reference, and if the list has multiple references to that target, then a change to one will be reflected in all. Use `copy.deepcopy()` when building your list to ensure that each list element will refer to a separate instance of the tuple.